# how to copy file to another path in dll?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I am trying to copy a file from a specific path to another.

The path that I targeted is `CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA`, which is Program Data, so I tried:

```
CopyFile(PChar(AppFolder +'\needed.dll'), PChar(anotherfolder+'\needed.dll'), False);
```

but it doesn't copy anything to the target path.

So I deiced to test the code inside an EXE application and it copies the file normally. What could be the problem? Why I am unable to copy files from a DLL?

Here is my `Appfolder` path:

```
function GetSpecialFolder(const CSIDL : integer) : String;
var
  RecPath : PWideChar;
begin
  RecPath := StrAlloc(MAX_PATH);
  try
    FillChar(RecPath^,MAX_PATH,0);
    if SHGetSpecialFolderPath(0,RecPath,CSIDL,false) then begin
      Result := RecPath;
    end else Result := '';
  finally
    StrDispose(RecPath);
  end;
end;

function AnotherFolder: string;
begin
  if IsWindowsVistaOrGreater then
  begin
    Result := GetSpecialFolder(CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA)+'\applocation';
  end;
end;

function AppFolder: string;
begin
  if IsWindowsVistaOrGreater then
  begin
    Result := GetSpecialFolder(CSIDL_INTERNET_CACHE)+'\Low\applocation';
  end else
    Result := GetSpecialFolder(CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA)+'\application';
    //Result := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName);
end;
```

Adding Actual code

```
// dll form

function GetSpecialFolder(const CSIDL: integer): String;
var
  RecPath: PWideChar;
begin
  RecPath := StrAlloc(MAX_PATH);
  try
    FillChar(RecPath^, MAX_PATH, 0);
    if SHGetSpecialFolderPath(0, RecPath, CSIDL, false) then
    begin
      Result := RecPath;
    end
    else
      Result := '';
  finally
    StrDispose(RecPath);
  end;
end;

function AnotherFolder: string;
begin
  // Vista check removed
  Result := GetSpecialFolder(CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA) + '\applocation';
end;

function AppFolder: string;
begin
  if IsWindowsVistaOrGreater then
  begin
    Result := GetSpecialFolder(CSIDL_INTERNET_CACHE) + '\Low\applocation';
  end
  else
    Result := GetSpecialFolder(CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA) + '\application';
  // Result := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName);
end;

procedure Tform1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if IsWindowsVistaOrGreater then
  begin
    CopyFile(PChar(AppFolder + '\needed.dll'), PChar(AnotherFolder + '\needed.dll'), false);
    memo1.Lines.Add('Value : ' + IntTostr(GetLastError()));
  end;
end;
```

my dll only have  1 form that when its shows it show  copy file from location to another .

manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity
    type="win32"
    name="DelphiApplication"
    version="1.0.0.0" 
    processorArchitecture="*"/>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity
        type="win32"
        name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
        version="6.0.0.0"
        publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
        language="*"
        processorArchitecture="*"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
```

project dll source

```
{$R apploadform.res' apploadform.rc'}
```

Comment: `StrAlloc` is deprecated and in any case you don't need dynamic allocation for a constant sized text buffer. Use a fixed length array instead.

Comment: Why is `anotherfolder()` singling out Vista+ for `CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA`? That CSIDL has been available since Windows 2000. And why is `AppFolder()` using `CSIDL_INTERNET_CACHE` at all? It should not be (unless you are writing a custom IE cache manager). Just use `CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA` unconditionally, it will work fine by itself on all Windows versions released in the past 1 1/2 decade.

Comment: @RemyLebeau the file that I want to copy is exist in CSIDL_INTERNET_CACHE . I wanted to copy that file from that temporarily internet files \low to programdata\ application

Comment: Why is this tagged freepascal and delphi?

Comment: I thought  this tags is concern

Comment: You aren't using both. What are you using.

Comment: I am using Delphi xe7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't checking for errors. The Win32 API function `CopyFile` returns a `Boolean` indicating success or failure. In your case I predict it will return `False`. You are then directed by the documentation (did you read it closely?) to call `GetLastError` to find out why the call failed. I predict that will yield a value of `5` which is `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. The reason for this is that `CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA` is secured against writing from standard user. You'd need to run your process elevated to be able to write there.

Of course, my guesswork here could be wrong. In that case, you will still be led to the answer by following this advice. If the function calls fail, the error codes will give you the reason why.

The big lesson to learn here, in my opinion, is the importance of error checking when calling Win32 API functions. You must pay close attention to the documentation, and follow the error checking procedures that it prescribes.

The other lesson is that when debugging you should simplify. Perhaps your code produces invalid paths. Perhaps `GetSpecialFolder` is broken. Perhaps you fail to add directory separators correctly. Step 1 of debugging is to check that the paths you pass to `CopyFile` are correct. Did you do that? Once you are happy with that then you can dig deeper. Certainly if that part of the code works then we don't need to see it here. You could have replaced that code and passed constants to `CopyFile`, for our benefit.

On the other hand, perhaps the paths that you pass to `CopyFile` are not what you expect them to be. You should have done some debugging to check those paths. Do you know what paths you pass to `CopyFile`? If not, you really should check they are as you expect.

Comment: I checked for `memo1.Lines.Add(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError()));` it gives The operation completed successfully

Comment: That's not how to check for errors. You have to check the return value. You cannot just call `GetLastError` at some arbitrary point in time. If you do get the error checking right, and `CopyFile` is succeeding, then the file is copied. If you don't see it then your paths are wrong. Really, I could not care less about your actual problem. What motivates me is to teach you how to debug. Are you interested in learning that skill?

Comment: sure I am interested to learn more . what makes things complicated that I tested the exact code in exe and it copy files normally , I double checked the location of files they are exist from where i want to copy

Comment: Great. So you need to do the error checking as I said in the first paragraph. And you need to check what parameters you actually send to `CopyFile`.

Comment: i will dig more into this

Comment: I deeply checked the result of `SHGetSpecialFolderPath` its returns `C:\ProgramData` also I checked the Copyfile if true but sadly its return false. on dll . and return true on exe

Comment: And what does `GetLastError()` report when `CopyFile()` returns false?

Comment: on dll value gives 80 , weird to give that file exist even if its not exist

Comment: @RemyLebeau when set to true gives value 80 , when set to false gives value 0

Comment: @DelphiStudent: Calling `GetLastError()` is *meaningless* when `CopyFile()` returns true. And the *only* way `GetLastError()` can return 0 when `CopyFile()` returns false is if you do something else that resets the error code before you call `GetLastError()`. You **must** call `GetLastError()` *immediately* after `CopyFile()` fails, before doing *anything* else.

Comment: You cannot write to `C:\ProgramData` unless your process is elevated. You should be seeing error code 5 when you try to do that from a non-elevated process.

Comment: I did call 'Getlasterror()' immediately after copy file in fact no task are called after copying file

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: you can't write to `ProgramData` directly, but you can write to a subfolder instead.

Comment: @DelphiStudent: It is physically impossible for `GetLastError()` to return 0 *immediately* after `CopyFile()` returns false. You would have to be calling something in between that resets the error code before you are calling `GetLastError()`. Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37168071/edit) to show the actual code you are using to copy the file and check the error code. You are clearly doing something wrong, but we cannot see it.

Comment: 80 is `ERROR_FILE_EXISTS` which I guess is a clue. You still need to complete the debugging task. Find out what paths are being passed to `CopyFile`.

Comment: You still aren't checking for errors. You still haven't logged the values you pass to CopyFile.

Comment: I have posted an answer that shows how to do all of that.

Answer (score 1):

Try something more like this instead:

```
uses
  ..., SysUtils, Windows, ShlObj;

function GetSpecialFolder(const iFolder: Integer; OwnerWnd: HWND = 0): String;
var
  RecPath: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
begin
  if SHGetSpecialFolderPath(OwnerWnd, RecPath, iFolder, False) then
    Result := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(RecPath)
  else
    Result := '';
end;

function AnotherFolder(OwnerWnd: HWND = 0): string;
begin
  Result := GetSpecialFolder(CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA, OwnerWnd) + 'applocation' + PathDelim;
end;

function AppFolder(OwnerWnd: HWND = 0): string;
begin
  Result := GetSpecialFolder(CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA, OwnerWnd) + 'application' + PathDelim;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  Source, Target: String;
  ErrCode: DWORD;
begin
  Source := AppFolder(Handle) + 'needed.dll';
  Target := AnotherFolder(Handle) + 'needed.dll';

  Memo1.Lines.Add('Source: ' + Source);
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Target: ' + Target);

  if CopyFile(PChar(Source), PChar(Target), false) then
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Copied OK');
  end else
  begin
    ErrCode := GetLastError;
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Unable to copy! Error ' + IntTostr(ErrCode) + '. ' + SysErrorMessage(ErrCode));
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I tried your code it gives Copied OK ! but no files has been copied to the path folder is empty and this is the actual problem from the begining

Comment: You still have not told us what parameters you pass to CopyFile. We need to know the values. I asked if you wanted to learn about debugging. You said yes. You don't seem to be listening.

Comment: the parameters I pass to same as in this answer CopyFile(PChar(Source), PChar(Target), false); which return  Source: C:\Users\deltauser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Low\applocation\needed.dll
Target: C:\ProgramData\applocation\needed.dll
Copied OK

Comment: So can we have a version of your code that passes literals to CopyFile. And is your all virtualized? Do you have an application manifest.

Comment: i will create one and test

Comment: Without an app manifest that specifies a `requestedExecutionLevel` value, your app's process might be writing the target file to a subfolder within the VirtualStore (`%LOCALAPPDATA%\VirtualStore`).

Comment: yup. That's what makes sense. Virtualization explains it.

Comment: I added manifest still have the same issue , and yes remy exactly that's what happened the file has been copied but cant been seen , I know this because I load some images from it and images shows X that's means its loads but location not found what I have to do in this case ?

Comment: @DelphiStudent: Did you verify that the file is actually being copied to the VirtualStore or not? In your manifest, try using `urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3` for the `TrustInfo`. Are you *sure* your manifest is compiled into the EXE? What is a `.REC` file, and how did you create it? It should be a `.RES` file instead, preferably created by compiling a `.RC` file. Given your lack of basic error handling skills, are you *sure* the problem is actually related to bad file paths, and not some other error in your code, such as loading the images incorrectly? Have you actually *debugged* the code?

Comment: the manifest compiled in dll I will change apploadform to apploadform.dll my bad . I go into virtualstore I found path names instead and not found dll inside it I create REC file like so brcc32 apploadform.RC -foapploadform.REC  in command linemy rc file looks like this `1 24 "foapploadform.manifest"`

Comment: changed the manifest still unable to visual the dll to the location

Comment: manifesting the DLL is not going to change the virtualization state of the process. Your host process is probably virtualized.  This is now a quite ridiculous question where we debug your problem by guesswork with hardly any knowledge. We are able to do it because we've seen so many similar errors. What you really need to do is learn the debugging skills that are missing. If you don't do that you are doomed to ask this sort of question forever more. I'm not sure you really appreciate that yet.

Comment: You cannot apply a manifest to a DLL, only to an EXE.  If the EXE gets virtualized, the DLL will also get virtualized. There is no getting around that other than to apply an appropriate manifest to the EXE so the DLL inherits the EXE's virtualization settings.

Comment: @Remy Minor nitpick. You can apply a manifest to a DLL. That can be useful for isolation purposes, activation contexts etc. For the purpose of virtualization, yes of course the executable determines that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: ok, then for purposes of UAC and virtualization, any manifest on the DLL is ignored.

Comment: @RemyLebeau that dll called from internet explorer with ocx application using load library so in this case I cant .access windows folders like into exe ?

Comment: @DelphiStudent: Internet Explorer runs in a "Protected Mode" with low integrity permissions by default, to protect the system from malicious websites/downloads. So any OCX/DLL running in an IE process under this mode cannot access things that require higher permissions. See [Understanding and Working in Protected Mode Internet Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250462.aspx) for more details.

Comment: what if I add manifest to the ocx link the one that I update now in my question

Comment: @DelphiStudent: It doesn't matter. An OCX is a DLL, just with a different file extension and exported functions to support ActiveX. As such, it still runs inside of IE's process, and is subject to IE's manifest for purposes of UAC and virtualization.  At the DLL/OCX level, there is *nothing* you can do about the virtualization issue, except to *stop* accessing folders that are subject to virtualization. The only reason they are virtualized in the first place is because people wrote bad security code in legacy days and the virtualization is to "protect" code that is still making bad mistakes.